# Do you have any additions or alterations to this list of popular audio formats?

Tags: audio, file-sharing, file-format

I am trying to compile a list of **common** audio file formats used in both personal storage and peer transmission. I have compiled the following list, do you think that there are any significant formats missing? Are any of them not actually common formats? Any advice/alterations are highly useful.

advanced audio coding,
 apple lossless audio file,
 atrac3 audio file,
 atrac audio file,
 audio interchange file format,
 core audio file,
 free lossless audio codec file,
 mpeg 1 audio layer 3,
 mpeg 2 audio,
 mpeg 4 audio book file,
 musical instrument digital interface,
 ogg vorbis compressed audio file,
 open media framework file,
 real audio,
 real audio media,
 waveform audio file format,
 windows media audio.

Comment: Common is an extremely relative term.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a nice [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format) for audio file formats which might help you building your list. The article includes:

- Uncompressed audio formats
- Lossless compressed audio formats
- Free and open file formats
- Open file formats
- Proprietary formats